# Calculator Using Fuctions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function

I'm a college student learning c++, so I'm making a simple calculator using functions. The program is finished and is rid of errors, but for some reason i"m getting 2 errors. I tried to fix but I still can't figure out to fix it. The errors and my code is below. Can someone help me and tell me how to fix this problem ? I use Visual Studio 2017. and if you want, help revise my code

ERRORS:

```
Errors 1 C4700  uninitialized local variable 'num1' Line 31
Errors 2 C4700  uninitialized local variable 'num2' Line 31
```

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

double AddNum(int num1, int num2);
double SubNum(int num1, int num2);
double MultNum(int num1, int num2);
double DiviNum(int num1, int num2);


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, option;

    string MENU = "Menu \n1 = Add\n2 = Subtract\n3 = Multiply\n4 = Divide\n5 = Raise to the Power\n6 = Even or Odd\n7 Quit";// this will output a list of usable programs to use
    cout << MENU << "\n Please select your option (#1-7)" << endl;
    cin >> option;
    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
    {
     AddNum(num1, num2);
    cout << "Please enter an integer:";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
    cin >> num2;

    cout << "The sum of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is " << num1 + num2 << endl;
    break;
    }
    case 2:
    { SubNum(num1, num2);
    cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
    cin >> num2;

    cout << "The difference of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is " << num1 - num2 << endl;
    break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
         MultNum(num1, num2);
        cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
        cin >> num1;

        cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
        cin >> num2;

        cout << "The product of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is " << num1 * num2 << endl;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        DiviNum(num1, num2);
    cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "The quotient of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is " << num1 / num2 << endl;
    break;
    }


        case 5:
        {
            cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
            cin >> num1;

            cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
            cin >> num2;

            double x = num1;
            cout << pow(x, num2);
            cout << "The Number of" << x << " raised to the power of" << num2 << "is" << pow(x, num2) << endl;
            break;
        }

        case 6:
        {
            cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
            cin >> num1;

            if (num1 % 2 == 0)
                cout << "The Number Is EVEN.";

            else
                cout << "The Number Is ODD";
            break;
        }

        case 7:
        {
            cout << "You are now Leaving the Calculator, GOODBYE !!! " << endl;
            break;
        }

        default:
        {cout << "Invalid Entry!\nPlease re-run the program and " << endl;
        cout << "enter a valid menu choice.\n";
        break;
        }
    }


       system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: try implementing your program using Object oriented concepts (ie class and object), that is the basic of C++. your solution may not be considered as c++ solution in your college rather they will say it as c code.

Answer (score 3):

You try to use variables that have no values before you set values. That’s not ok and the logic in your code is wrong:

```
case 4:
{
    DiviNum(num1, num2);
cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
cin >> num1;

cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
cin >> num2;
cout << "The quotient of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is " << num1 / num2 << endl;
break;
}
```

You’re calling `DiviNum` first and then asking for numbers. Why? You need to ask for numbers first and then do the calculation. Your errors go away and the code actually works. So move the call to happen at the right spot in all calculations.

Your code also does nothing with the declared functions actually since you don’t save the result and calculate the result inline. Probably not what was wanted.

Do not set default values to variables as suggested by others unless they’re actually needed and rational, otherwise you’ll run into hard to find problems.

Answer (score 0):

**"Errors 1 C4700  uninitialized local variable 'num1' Line 31
Errors 2 C4700  uninitialized local variable 'num2' Line 31 "**

Compiler Warning C4700 :uninitialized local variable 'name' used. The local variable name has been used, that is, read from, before it has been assigned a value. In C and C++, local variables are not initialized by default. Uninitialized variables can contain any value, and their use leads to undefined behavior.

To fix this issue, you can initialize local variables when they are declared, or assign a value to them before they are used. A function can be used to initialize a variable that's passed as a reference parameter, or when its address is passed as a pointer parameter.

I agree with Sami Kuhmonen, you should enter "num1" and "num2" first. And then call operator (AddNum, SubNum, MultNum, DiviNum).

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <iomanip>

    double AddNum(int num1, int num2);
    double SubNum(int num1, int num2);
    double MultNum(int num1, int num2);
    double DiviNum(int num1, int num2);



    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int num1, num2, option;



    string MENU = "Menu \n1 = Add\n2 = Subtract\n3 = Multiply\n4 = Divide\n5 = Raise to the Power\n6 = Even or Odd\n7 Quit";// this will output a list of usable programs to use
    cout << MENU << "\n Please select your option (#1-7)" << endl;
    cin >> option;
    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
    {

        cout << "Please enter an integer:";
        cin >> num1;

        cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
        cin >> num2;
        AddNum(num1, num2);
        cout << "The sum of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is " << num1 + num2 << endl;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    { 
    cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
    cin >> num2;
    SubNum(num1, num2);
    cout << "The difference of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is " << num1 - num2 << endl;
    break;
    }
    case 3:
    {

        cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
        cin >> num1;

        cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
        cin >> num2;
        MultNum(num1, num2);
        cout << "The product of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is " << num1 * num2 << endl;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {

        cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
        cin >> num1;

        cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
        cin >> num2;

        DiviNum(num1, num2);

        cout << "The quotient of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is " << num1 / num2 << endl;
        break;
    }


    case 5:
    {
        cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
        cin >> num1;

        cout << "Please enter another integer:  ";
        cin >> num2;

        double x = num1;
        cout << pow(x, num2);
        cout << "The Number of" << x << " raised to the power of" << num2 << "is" << pow(x, num2) << endl;
        break;
    }

    case 6:
    {
        cout << "Please enter an integer:  ";
        cin >> num1;

        if (num1 % 2 == 0)
            cout << "The Number Is EVEN.";

        else
            cout << "The Number Is ODD";
        break;
    }

    case 7:
    {
        cout << "You are now Leaving the Calculator, GOODBYE !!! " << endl;
        break;
    }

    default:
    {cout << "Invalid Entry!\nPlease re-run the program and " << endl;
    cout << "enter a valid menu choice.\n";
    break;
    }
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer is that the compiler warning is correct. num1, num2, and option are declared but not initialized. As ints, you would typically initialize them to 0.

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int option = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

You declare these variables in `int num1, num2, option;` but you don't initialize them to any value. Just do:

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, option = 0;
```

Non static local variables of primitive types like these, are not initialized automatically, you must do it manually.